# Odoo OpenERP 8 invoice number custom

Tags: numbers, odoo, invoice

I'm coding an invoice inherited from account.invoice, the class looks like

```
class my_invoice(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'account.invoice'
     my_number = fields.Char(store=True, compute='_compute_my_number')
     my_sequence = fields.Many2One(comodel_name='my_sequence.model')

@api.one
@api.depends('state')
def _compute_my_number(self):
      if self.state == 'draft':
             self.my_number = 'DRAFT:' + self.my_sequence.number
      elif self.state == 'open':
             self.my_number = 'OPEN:' + self.my_sequence.number
      elif self.state == 'paid':
             self.my_number = 'PAID:' + self.my_sequence.number
```

Well, and I made a new view inherited from account.invoice_form including on it the field my_number

The problem is, everything works fine when the invoice is draft or open but when I make a payment, then my_number is empty.

Any ideas

Comment: `@api.one` should be ok, except that is deprecated since Odoo 9. Did you debug into your `_compute_my_number`? It should be invoked on payments that are enough to balance the invoice. If not, maybe there is a "no recompute" signal on that process.